# Powershell JSON - Always a single item, assigning to a variable

Tags: json, powershell

Forgive the basic question that shows how little I know about Powershell and JSON.

I think this is pretty straightforward, I have simplified the code.

```
$json = @"
{
"command": "restart"
}
"@

$Response = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Json

Write $Response

if($Command.Equals('restart')) { }
```

Basically, I will only ever receive a single JSON item Command X.

I just want to assign that Command to a variable.  So that If "restart" then restart.  What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will be different commands and you need to do something based on that response, the approach I would use is using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-switch?view=powershell-7.1):

```
$json = @"
{
"command": "restart"
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

switch($json.command)
{
    Restart { 
        # Your code if command = 'Restart'
    }
    CommandX { }
    CommandY { }
    Default {
        # This is could be for an unexpected command or something
        # that can happend if command is none of the above
    }

}
```

**Note:** This is assuming that the property will always be named **`command`**.